# ¿Cómo devolver datos de PHP a JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

**¿Se puede devolver datos desde php a javaScript?**
Me explico:
Yo hago una Ajax a un archivo php que contiene un insert a la base de datos, una vez se ejecute el insert quiero que me diga si lo hizo correctamente o si falló.
Os dejo el código para que os hagáis una ida:
JavaScript

```
function enviar(){
    n++
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/insertar.php",
        data: datos[n-1],
        dataType: "text",
        async:true,
        complete: function () {
            if(cantidad.value != n){
                crear.setAttribute('onclick','enviar()');
               document.getElementById('crear').click()
            }else{
                fin();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$departamento = $_POST['departamento'];
$sociedad = $_POST['sociedad']; 
$acFijo = $_POST['acFijo'];
$anio = $_POST['anio'];
$fechaActual = $_POST['fechaActual'];
$codeBar = $_POST['codeBar'];
$subcodigo = $_POST['subcodigo']; 

$pdo=new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=PC01INFORMATICA\SQLEXPRESS;Database=InventarioAF", "", "");
$statement=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO [dbo].[ACTIVOFIJOSINASIGNAR]
([TIPOAF],[SOCIEDAD],[EJERCICIO],[DEPARTAMENTO],[CODEBAR],[SUBCODIGO],[TEXTO])
VALUES
('$acFijo','$sociedad','$anio','$departamento','$codeBar','$subcodigo','$fechaActual')");
$statement->execute();
?>
```

En el caso de que fallara la consulta que me devolviera algún error al javaScript para poder solucionarl.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: usa el success de ajax para saber si se completo exitosamente tu envio y  error para obtener los errores

Comment: aqui tienes un buen ejemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38794652/insert-into-database-mysql-using-ajax-and-php

Comment: Lee sobre inyección SQL y cómo evitarla en PHP, el código compartido es vulnerable a ese tipo de ataques.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro ... su comentario es un poco inútil en este caso ya que no aporta nada a mi pregunta. Gracias

Comment: @YasielHernández es cuestión de perspectiva. Puede que dentro del contexto de la pregunta en sí no sea muy útil, pero teniendo en cuenta que la pregunta ya tiene respuesta (los comentarios de Tegito123) y en un contexto un poco más amplio, es una recomendación bastante útil. Mi intención no era hacer una crítica negativa sino un comentario constructivo.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro su aporte me parece bueno, pero  el comentario es útil si fuera a desplegar la aplicación o algo así, pero simplemente estoy aprendiendo "programación" y creo que aportar el código que hago ayuda a que las personas en esta plataforma puedan ayudarme, ya que no tengo riesgo de una inyección ya que esto se ejecuta en local,   
De todas formas me parece muy interesante y leeré sobre la inyección SQL, cuando llegue el momento, muchas gracias.

Comment: @Tegito123 Muchas gracias me sirvió de mucho!